# What's the solution of “Program type already present:com.android.volley.Cache$Entry”?

Tags: android

Error :

> Program type already present: com.android.volley.Cache$Entry
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   com.android.volley.Cache$Entry, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have added volley and gson twice:

```
implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
implementation files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
```

and

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

better remove those local libraries (which barely make any sense), in order to be notified about new versions (that's why some of those dependencies are being marked with yellow background color).

and you can also remove those four `-rc02` tags ...because the final version is out already.

next time, please don't post screenshots, because it is bothersome to copy text from an image.

Comment: Thank u.  I have already implemented those librairies, but, the same error.

Comment: @AidaFarhati you don't have to implement anything, you have to delete those jars.